# How can I remove just the title from a text

Tags: java, html

How can I remove just the title from the text shown below. The text includes all html tags, and the title tags are included as well, so maybe i can try to use the opening title tag and closing title tag to remove the title text, and keep everything else. What is the best way to do this?

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<META NAME="Docdate" CONTENT="05/02/2011">
<META NAME="m_title" CONTENT="TWO SECURITY GUARDS HACKED TO DEATH DURING A FIGHT">
<META NAME="m_author" CONTENT="">
<TITLE>MALAYSIA NEWS -- GENERAL NEWS -- 05/02/2011 -- TWO SECURITY GUARDS HACKED TO DEATH DURING A FIGHT</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY BACKGROUND="#FFFFFF">
<PRE>
05/02/2011

POLICE-FIGHT

TWO SECURITY GUARDS HACKED TO DEATH DURING A FIGHT





    KUALA LUMPUR, Feb 5 (Bernama) -- Two security guards were hacked to death in

a fight that broke out at Damansara Perdana construction site last night. 

    Both men, aged 20 and 26, were found dead at the scene with slash wounds on

their bodies in the 8.20pm incident. 

    Petaling Jaya OCPD ACP Arjunaidi Mohammed said the fight started following

an argument involving a security guard and several foreign workers at the site. 

    "One of them had an argument with several of the workers. He then called two

of his friends who are also security guards but working in other areas. 

    "A group of 12 to 15 foreign workers, carrying sharp weapons, then attacked

them," he told reporters at the scene today. 

    The other security guard managed to flee to safety, he added. 

    "The foreign workers had also left the area. We have picked up a security

guard in the area and two Indonesian workers to have their statements taken," he

said, adding that a manhunt was underway for the suspects. 

    -- BERNAMA 

    NMR AKT JS





</PRE>
<BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty common you shouldn't use Regexes to parse HTML, however. Here it is suitable:

```
String html = ...;
String withoutTitle = html.replaceAll("\\<TITLE\\>(.+)?\\</ ?TITLE\\>", "<TITLE> </TITLE>");
```

Comment: but then make sure html isn't too large to load in-memory.